# How to use SHA-1 dynamic key in Postman

Tags: javascript, security, sha, postman

I'm trying to use Postman to send a GET http request which contains a parameter which is dynamically generated by taking the full request query string (everything to the right of the question mark in the URL, after URL encoding), concatenating a previously assigned shared secret key, and then performing a SHA-1 hash of the resulting string.

I would use a Pre-request Script to achieve this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

I actually found a solution and would like to share it.

```js
var params = [
    ["client_id", "222"]
    ,["account_id", ""]
];

// Build the request body string from the Postman request.data object
var requestBody = "";
var firstpass = true;
for(var i=0;i < params.length; i++) {
        if(!firstpass){
            requestBody += "&";
        }
        requestBody += params[i][0] + "=" + params[i][1];
        firstpass = false;
        postman.setGlobalVariable(params[i][0], params[i][1]);
}
requestBody += postman.getEnvironmentVariable("sharedSecretKey");
postman.setGlobalVariable("requestBody", requestBody);

var mac = "";
if(requestBody){
    // SHA1 hash
    mac = CryptoJS.SHA1(requestBody);
}

postman.setGlobalVariable("mac", mac);
```

Then I just need to set the parameters in the URL : 
{{baseUrl}}/get?client_id={{client_id}}&account_id={{account_id}}&mac={{mac}}

where {{baseUrl}} is an environment variable
and {{client_id}}, {{account_id}} are global variables

Hope it can be helpful to someone.

Thank you.

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by [this answer](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/25384/40785), I used the following Postman pre-request script to create a SHA1 hash of a request.

Note that `request.data` is an implied variable and the `CryptoJS` library are provided by the [Postman Sandbox for pre-request scripts](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox/#requestresponse-related-properties).

```js
const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(request.data, 'yourSecret').toString();
pm.globals.set('hash', hash);
```

You can now reference the hash value as a postman global variable using `{{hash}}` syntax.

---

### Creating X-Hub-Signature Header like GitHub API Webhook Requests

My purpose in all this was to simulate the [`X-Hub-Signature`](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/#validating-payloads-from-github) header provided by the [GitHub Webhooks API](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) because my web service validates all webhook payloads to match the signature. So for me to test my web service, I also needed postman to generate a valid signature header.

Here's an adaptation of the above code snippet for generating the `X-Hub-Signature` request header value.

1. In GitHub, I set a [webhook secret](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/securing/) for my [GitHub App](https://developer.github.com/apps/).

[image: github webhook secret]

2. In Postman, I created an [environment](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/environments_and_globals/manage_environments/) and added the key=value pair `GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET` with the value I specified when I created my GitHub App.

[image: postman environment variable]

3. In Postman, I used the following pre-request script. It set the computed hash as a global variable.

```js
const hash = CryptoJS.HmacSHA1(
    request.data,
    pm.environment.get('GITHUB_WEBHOOK_SECRET')
).toString();
pm.globals.set('X-HUB-SIGNATURE', 'sha1=' + hash);
```

4. In Postman, I reference the global hash variable as a header in my requests, just like the GitHub Webhooks API will.

[image: postman request header]

Comment: It is worth saying to anyone else picking this up that if you end up with the word "object" being passed to your API then you need to add `.toString()` to the end of the const line